# How to run multi custom protocols from browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, protocols

Now I want to handle custom protocols like: app1://params, app2://params from browser.
When run auto by code (ex on-page-load: `window.location.href = 'appname://params'`) 1 protocols, it's ok. 
But if run multi protocols browser will prevent 2nd protocols and show err:

> Not allowed to launch 'appname://some-params' because a user gesture
> is required.

How to disable check user guesture to run multi protocols from browser for dev purpose?

Comment: What do you mean by "run multi protocols" ?

Comment: i mean i have 2 protocols for my app. appname1://params, appname2://params. I want to run 2 protocols at same time (sequence) to launch my app.

Comment: Please add to the question the exact string you are supplying to href.

Comment: this protocols string just like 'mailto:no-one@snai1mai1.com?subject=free chocolate'. You don't install my app so it's no mean when use test it.

Comment: I don't need the exact protocol - but need to see how you are trying to run the so called "multi protocol".  In other words, what do you exactly supply for this - " run multi protocols from browser "

Comment: this is real example: when user click btn i call func have folowing content: window.location.href = 'mailtoiiiii://'; window.location.href = 'mailto://'; First protocols is will perform but the second will be blocked by browser

Answer (score 0):

As transpired via the comments, you are trying to open two different urls with two different protocols in a single function call.

You can use `window.open` instead of `window.location.href` for this purpose.

```
function runApps() {
  window.open('mailto:foo@foo.com');
  window.open('mailto:bar@bar.com');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in my case, I don't want to open in other tab. because I need do some check (protocols was open success or not) on curent tab.